# How to change color of 1 word in Array list item

Tags: android

For example I have an arraylist and an Item in it (`"Some important words"`), and I need to change color only on the word "important"

Answer (score 0):

1. First create an arraylist of your important words.
2. Then create an arraylist for words which you want to check.
3. Then check your word or word list items contains or matches a word in important words arraylist. Try below code.

   ```
   ArrayList Important_Word_List = new ArrayList<String>(); //create array list for important words
   Important_Word_List.add("Important Name1"); //add important words to Important_Word_List
   Important_Word_List.add("Important Name2");

   ArrayList MyWord_List = new ArrayList<String>(); //create array list for checking words
   MyWord_List.add("Word1"); //add words to MyWord_List, which you want to check
   MyWord_List.add("Word2");

   TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); //create reference for text view or widget

   for (int i = 0; i < MyWord_List.size(); i++) { //iterate through MyWord_List
       if (Important_Word_List.contains(MyWord_List.get(i).toString())) { //check the word is a important word or not
           textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd")); //for important word, set specific color to textview or widget
       } else {
           textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ddbdbd")); //if not a important word, set default color
       }
   }
   ```